# Simple Ajax from Rails tutorial is sending the request but not outputing the HTML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm following this tutorial about making an Ajax request on Rails:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/

**made _form remote:**
    <%= form_for(@post, :remote => true) do |f| %>

**My scripts are loaded:**

```
  <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Added format.js to posts_controller.rb:**

```
  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.js 
      end
    end
  end
```

**Created create.js.erb:**

```
$('body').html("<h1><%= escape_javaScript(@post.title) %></h1>").append("<%= escape_javaScript(@post.content) %>");
```

But when I click the submit button nothing happens in the view but the posts are being created.
I just get this in the terminal:

> Started POST "/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-06 12:58:02 +0800
>   Processing by PostsController#create as JS   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"m4BT19I9aUQ+FwGD3Ub9WqKJc0IqjsPpD8+nOyQNhjo=",
>   "post"=>{"name"=>"asdsad", "title"=>"sadassad",
>   "content"=>"adasdadadad"}, "commit"=>"Create Post"}    (0.2ms)  begin
>   transaction   SQL (86.7ms)  INSERT INTO "posts" ("content",
>   "created_at", "name", "title", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
>   [["content", "adasdadadad"], ["created_at", Mon, 06 Feb 2012 04:58:02
>   UTC +00:00], ["name", "asdsad"], ["title", "sadassad"], ["updated_at",
>   Mon, 06 Feb 2012 04:58:02 UTC +00:00]]    (120.0ms)  commit
>   transaction   Rendered posts/create.js.erb (307.9ms) Completed 500
>   Internal Server Error in 528ms
>
> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `escape_javaScript' for
>
> ## <#:0xb78ecd0>):
>
> ```
> 1:    $('body').html("<h1><%= escape_javaScript(@post.title) %></h1>").append("<%= escape_javaScript(@post.content) %>");
> ```
>
> app/views/posts/create.js.erb:1:in
>   `_app_views_posts_create_js_erb__76139275_96235900'
>
>   app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:45:in`create'
>
> Rendered
>   /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb
>   (9.9ms)   Rendered
>   /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb
>   (3.1ms)   Rendered
>   /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb
>   within rescues/layout (19.1ms)

Any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a typing error in that tutorial; `escape_javaScript` should be `escape_javascript` (lower case)

See also: [`escape_javascript()`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript)